# Is this one-hot encoding in TensorFlow fast? Or flawed for any reason?

Tags: tensorflow

There are a few stack overflow questions about computing one-hot embeddings with TensorFlow, and here is the accepted solution:

```
num_labels = 10
sparse_labels = tf.reshape(label_batch, [-1, 1])
derived_size = tf.shape(label_batch)[0]
indices = tf.reshape(tf.range(0, derived_size, 1), [-1, 1])
concated = tf.concat(1, [indices, sparse_labels])
outshape = tf.reshape(tf.concat(0, [derived_size, [num_labels]]), [-1])
labels = tf.sparse_to_dense(concated, outshape, 1.0, 0.0)
```

This is almost identical to the code in an official tutorial: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/0.6.0/tutorials/mnist/tf/index.html

To me it seems that since `tf.nn.embedding_lookup` exists, it's probably more efficient. Here's a version that uses this, and it supports arbitrarily-shaped inputs:

```
def one_hot(inputs, num_classes):
    with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
        table = tf.constant(np.identity(num_classes, dtype=np.float32))
        embeddings = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(table, inputs)
    return embeddings
```

Do you expect this implementation to be faster? And is it flawed for any other reason?

Comment: `inferior` is a subjective quality. Can you express it in an objective manner. e.g. time, memory, produces errors; something that can be measured.

Comment: What you're asking will be obvious to TensorFlow developers, but it's not to me. I've found the TensorFlow examples to be solid: more than once I've thought I was improving something and later realized that they were very careful in their design (though with lacking documentation). To me, this one-hot encoder is better (more readable, more general, potentially faster), but I'm asking to see if it's flawed in a way that I don't see.

Comment: I understand. I added the comment because StackOverflow has specific requirements for questions and if new people see this they might start asking more subjective questions which aren't allowed. The TensorFlow tag is more forgiving but if standards aren't keep then the tag will become of no value, and I would like to use it for a long time.

Comment: I see. I edited it to make it a bit more specific.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `one_hot()` function in your question looks correct. However, the reason that we do not recommend writing code this way is that it is **very memory inefficient**. To understand why, let's say you have a batch size of 32, and 1,000,000 classes.

- In the version suggested in the tutorial, the largest tensor will be the result of [`tf.sparse_to_dense()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sparse_to_dense), which will be `32 x 1000000`.
- In the `one_hot()` function in the question, the largest tensor will be the result of `np.identity(1000000)`, which is 4 terabytes. Of course, allocating this tensor probably won't succeed. Even if the number of classes were much smaller, it would still waste memory to store all of those zeroes explicitly—TensorFlow does not automatically convert your data to a sparse representation even though it might be profitable to do so.

Finally, I want to offer a plug for a new function that was recently added to the open-source repository, and will be available in the next release. [`tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits) allows you to specify a vector of integers as the labels, and saves you from having to build the dense one-hot representation. It should be much more efficient that *either* solution for large numbers of classes.

Comment: Prompted by mrry's answer, I've changed the existing MNIST convolutional.py and CIFAR models to use this new op, so they're useful as an example:  https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10.py#L270

Comment: One thing is still very unclear to me: Why does memory in the computational graph matter more than the memory used to store the training data? Storing one-hot-encoded training data with 1,000,000 classes seems impossible.